# Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/analytics.node'

Tags: node.js, zenbot

After following the instructions to install it (from what i can tell)
I am getting this error when trying to install the software:

```
C:\zenbot\zenbot>npm install
enter code herenpm ERR! path C:\zenbot\zenbot\node_modules\forex.analytics
npm ERR! code EISGIT
npm ERR! git C:\zenbot\zenbot\node_modules\forex.analytics: Appears to be a git
repo or submodule.

npm ERR! git     C:\zenbot\zenbot\node_modules\forex.analytics
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Spork\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-29T22_35_31_
500Z-debug.log
```

Afterwards, I am getting this error when trying to run the software after completing the install:

```
C:\zenbot\zenbot>node zenbot.js
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/analytics.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(C:\zenbot\zenbot\node_modules\forex.analytics\index.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the inclusion of [`forex.analytics`](https://github.com/mkmarek/forex.analytics), running on bare Windows is broken.

The recommended path is to either use the Bash and Linux subsystem option from Windows features, or run in a Docker container.

See: [Update documentation for Windows users](https://github.com/DeviaVir/zenbot/issues/420) at GitHub.